# Jest is not running tests cases in parallel

Tags: node.js, jestjs

As per JEST documents if the test cases are in separate files/folder they should run in parallel and in my other projects they do in fact run in parallel, but in my current project my test cases are in different files but for some reason they are running sequentially, the test cases take 20-30 minutes per file and I have 7 such files so the total test execution time is close to 1 hr 30 minutes.

I am trying to figure out why the JEST will run test cases in parallel even if they are in separate files, I am using a common method to trigger all the test cases can that be the reason ?

by common method I mean, all the test cases are passing different arguments to the same method.

I have gone through the JEST documents but I am unable to figure out why JEST will run tests sequentially even though they are in separate files, I am not using any options with jest CLI command, ( not using runInband etc )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following this [link](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/5818) I figured out that by using --maxWorker flag we can run test cases in parallel if they don't run in parallel by default